# Cannot send mail using PHPmailer or swift mailer

Tags: php, xampp, smtp, phpmailer, swiftmailer

When using PHPmailer or swift mailer to send mail through mail.google.com, both timeout after 30 seconds. The PHPmailer code is as follows

```
<?php
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'mail.google.com';            // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = '[my email]@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '[password]';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('[my email]@gmail.com', 'Adam Johnston');
    $mail->addAddress('[my email]@gmail.com', 'Adam Johnston');     // Add a recipient
    //$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    //$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    //Attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Here is the swift mailer code:

```
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

// Create the Transport
$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('mail.google.com', 465))
  ->setUsername('[my email]@gmail.com')
  ->setPassword('[password]')
;

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

// Create a message
$message = (new Swift_Message('Wonderful Subject'))
  ->setFrom(['[my email]@gmail.com' => 'Adam Johnston'])
  ->setTo(['[my email]@gmail.com' => 'Adam Johnston'])
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
  ;

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Because both are timing out, I'm assuming both are installed correctly but I've set something up incorrectly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For gmail the SMTP server (`Host` field) should be `smtp.gmail.com`.

Comment: That gives the following error:

Uncaught Swift_TransportException: Connection could not be established with host smtp.google.com [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. #0]

Comment: Error message mentions _smtp.google.com_, not _smtp.gmail.com_.

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot. Still, that gave me the following: Fatal error: Uncaught Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. e4-v6sm1491895oti.75 - gsmtp "

Comment: Nevermind. I fixed it by changing to TLS and changing the port to 587. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by changing to TLS and changing the port to 587. Thanks to Jiri for pointing out my stupid typos as well.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you've enabled "Less secure apps" for your account so that password authentication is enabled for Gmail. By default it is NOT enabled, and only OAUTH authentication is allowed (which can't be used over SMTP). https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: You don't have to do this. OAuth can be used for email. It's very painful to set up, but it does work, and PHPMailer supports it, see examples and docs about it.